# Second-order expected value given threshold

Tags: probability

Suppose that $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$ are uniform, independent random variables in $[0,1]$, and let $r\in[0,1]$. Suppose that the variables are ordered as $Y_1\geq Y_2\geq ...\geq Y_n$. Given that $Y_2\geq r$, what is the expected value of $Y_2$?